# Running a Cloud Firestore transaction inside a Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

How can the data in `event.data.data()` be passed into a transaction, as the read value?

```js
exports.runMyTransaction = functions.firestore
    .doc('/myCollection/{myId}').onWrite((event) => {

    // In this transaction, I want to pass event instead of cityRef
    var transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
    return t.get(cityRef)
        .then(doc => {
        // doc should contain the event object
        var newPopulation = doc.data().population + 1;
        t.update(cityRef, { population: newPopulation });
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: You might want to add some more detail about what exactly you're trying to accomplish.  Maybe also some some code you're working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass your own "current value" into a transaction. But since Cloud Functions are only triggered after the data has been committed, getting the data in a transaction should give you the same value in documents with low contention.

In fact: if it doesn't give the same value, that is because somebody else already changed the document again. And that case it's precisely why you can't pass in your own "this is the current value".

This sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you update your question to tell what you're trying to accomplish, and possibly the code that is giving problems?

Comment: I was trying to avoid the latency of an extra read, when the value has already been passed into the function.  I can easily get it again, if that's the only solution.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it a bit more. Since Firebase RTDB & Cloud Firestore transactions are a compare-and-set operation, there is actually no danger in setting your own initial guess. While I don't think the roundtrip matter much in the context of Cloud Functions, it might be worth filing a feature request on the [Admin SDK repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node), just to see how others respond.

Comment: Thinking further, if the transaction has to retry, because another user is writing to the document, it may be best to get an "up to date" version of the document, each time.  Whereas, the event data may be stale by the 2nd or 3rd time that the transaction tries to process.